# stored procedure and triggers in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers, sequence

I'm  trying to run a stored procedure that will insert data to the table. In in the table, there is a trigger after add that will update the sequence table(there is no sequence in MySQL DB)

This is my stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`dbName`@`%` PROCEDURE `insertGuide`(m_name varchar(45)  ,m_last varchar(45) ,addres varchar(45) ,mphone int)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO `guides` (`id`, `name`, `lastName`, `address`, `phone`)
select max(id)+1, m_name, m_last, addres, mphone
from seq;

END
```

This is my trigger:

```
USE `dbName`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`dbName`@`%` TRIGGER 
    guidesUpdate
AFTER INSERT ON
    guides
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO seq VALUES ();
    END
```

when I run

```
call insertGuide('a'  ,'aa' ,'aaa' ,'12333')
```

it returns an error:

> Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'seq' in stored function/trigger
>   because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored
>   function/trigger.

Can I do something about it?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is to eliminate this trigger entirely.  If you want to have an auto-incrementing id on a table, then simply define it in the `create table` statement:

```
create table guides as (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    . . .
);
```